# Question on proving that the rationals are countably infinite

Tags: functions, rational-numbers

I just a question on a proof for the rationals being countably infinite from a textbook. We consider the following function, a mapping from $\Bbb Q$ to $\Bbb N$

$$f(x) = \begin{cases}
0,  & \text{if $x$ = 0} \\
2^m 3^n, & \text{if $x$ > 0} \\
2^m 3^n \cdot 5  &\text{if $x$ < 0}
\end{cases} where\ x = \frac mn \ and \  gcd(m,n) = 1  $$

One can see that it is injective by the uniqueness of prime factorization but how is it surjective?

Comment: surjective onto what?

Comment: Onto the natural numbers. Added it now to the question

Comment: wait what? how could it possibly be surjective. how would you get 7

Comment: @mathworker21 What I was wondering. If we are trying to show that it is countably infinite then we wish to establish a bijection from Q to N and that what was given in the book

Comment: Or it is only necessary for there to be an injection between Q and N?

Comment: If you have an injection from a set $A$ to $\mathbb{N}$, then that shows $A$ is at most countably infinite. This is intuitive and easy to prove.

Comment: Side note:  The [Cantor Schroeder Bernstein Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schr%C3%B6der%E2%80%93Bernstein_theorem) constructs a bijection between two sets, $A,B$  given injections $A\to B$ and $B\to A$.

Comment: thanks for help guys